# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Cordova plug-in not getting executed

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to create a Cordova Plugin using IBM Worklight. I followed the instructions mentioned in the [IBM Worklight Getting Started page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova), but while checking trying it on a device I get the following:

> 02-13 17:58:15.182: D/PluginManager(21057): exec() call to unknown
>   plugin: SamPlugin

I added the plugin in **Config.xml** as follows:

```
<plugin name="SamPlugin" value="com.samapp.plugins.samplugin.SamPlugin"/>
```

and then, i called the plugin from my **JavaScript** file as follows:

```
cordova.exec(success,failure,"SamPlugin","printMsg",[name]);
```

There are no errors while building the application.
Do I need to mention the plugin anywhere else?

Comment: Please mention the environment... iOS? Android?

Comment: Sorry. Android platform

Comment: is this question resolved?

Comment: No. Unfortunately the solution you suggested is not working .

Comment: "not working"... what's not working? Can you provide your project?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the way you have declared the plug-in in config.xml is incorrect...

This:

```
<plugin name="SamPlugin" value="com.samapp.plugins.samplugin.SamPlugin"/>
```

Should be:

```
<feature name="SamPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.testapp.SamPlugin" />
</feature>
```

The above is the way Cordova plug-ins are declared in Cordova 3.x; Worklight 6.1 uses Cordova 3.1.

The above assumes you are using Worklight 6.1, because you mentioned that you've followed a Getting Started training module, which is now based on Worklight 6.1... **If you are using a different Worklight version, you must mention the version number**.

---

For example - an application that implements a Cordova plug-in that shares a link to a question via the native email app installed on the device (this doesn't really matter, it's just a "scenario"):

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="openExternalApp()">Share Question</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function openExternalApp() {
    var QUESTION_LINK = $(".question_link").attr("href");
    cordova.exec(onSuccess, onFailure, "OpenExternalAppPlugin", "openApp", [QUESTION_LINK]);
}

function onSuccess() {
    WL.Logger.debug("*** Plug-in executed successfully.");
}

function onFailure() {
    WL.Logger.debug("*** Plug-in failed to execute.");
}
```

**android\native\res\xml\config.xml:**

```
<feature name="OpenExternalAppPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.testapp.OpenExternalAppPlugin" />
</feature>
```

**android\native\src\com\YOUR_APP\OpenExternalAppPlugin.java:**
The Java file containing the Java code of the Cordova plug-in...