# errors with adding cordova sms plugin in worklight 6.0

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Nothing happening on clicking SEND button. Smsplugin.js disappears on building the app from assets/WWW in android environment. I have tried most ways around internet but nothing working.

SmsPlugin.js

```
var SmsPlugin = function () {};
SmsPlugin.prototype.SendSMS = function (successCallback,failureCallbackphone,        phone,message, method) {
return cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'SmsPlugin', "SendSMS",    [phone, message,method]);
};

cordova.addConstructor(function() {
cordova.addPlugin("SmsPlugin", new SmsPlugin());

});
```

Main javascript file

```
function send(){
var myElement = document.getElementById('btnDefaultSMS');
myElement.onclick = function() {
   var number = $("#numberTxt").val();
   var message = $("#messageTxt").val();
   window.SmsPlugin.SendSMS(number , message,
           function () {
alert('Message successfully sent to' + contactNumber);
 },
function (event) {
alert('Message failed due to:' + event);
}
,"INTENT");
};
}
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", send , false);
```

SmsPlugin.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

public class SmsPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
public final String ACTION_SEND_SMS = "SendSMS";

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals(ACTION_SEND_SMS)) {
        try {
            String phoneNumber = args.getString(0);
            String message = args.getString(1);
            String method = args.getString(2);

            if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("INTENT")){
                invokeSMSIntent(phoneNumber, message);
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult( PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT));
            } else{
                sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
            }

            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));
            return true;
        }
        catch (JSONException ex) {
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult( PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void invokeSMSIntent(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(sendIntent);
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.cordova.getActivity(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
    manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, null);
}
}
```

Comment: The assets/ folder is regenerated every time you build the application. If you want smsplugin.js, you should put it inside the common folder in the Worklight application, since that folder is the one that is copied every time you build to the assets/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to add a plug-in to a pure Cordova application, rather than a Worklight app... Have you [read the training materials for using Cordova plug-ins in Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova)?

See my answer to the following question, which details the HowTo. It also fits for "importing" existing plug-ins. The procedure is mostly the same*: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Cordova plug-in not getting executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754622/ibm-worklight-6-1-cordova-plug-in-not-getting-executed)

*You mention Worklight 6.0 rather than 6.1, so the difference would be in the structure of  declaring a plug-in in `config.xml`; just follow suite like the rest of the plug-in declarations in the file...

Comment: the method i have used is same as described in the training module of worklight and in javascript console i am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined

Comment: "cordova.addPlugin("SmsPlugin", new SmsPlugin());" This code snippet you've mentioned is most certainly not described in the training material. I cannot help you with the error you mention w/out understanding the context in which it appears - where and when. Edit your question appropriately.